# Folder android-maps-utils with Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, dependencies, libraries

I am new with using other libraries.I work with Android Studio and I would like to use android-maps-utils from this site https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils

My questions are: where should I add the dependencies

```
  dependencies {
   compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4+'
  }
```

In this file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.internet.myapp"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'
compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4+' 
}
```

or in this one?

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
}
```

I think i should add also the folder here:

```
Project Root
+-- libs
    +-- android-maps-utils-master (my lib project)
+-- app
|   +-- builds
|   +-- src
|   |   +-- main (java code and resources)
    +-- .....
+--settings.gradle
```

But is it right put all the unzipped folder, or I should put only the folder "library" that is inside of it?Thanks in advance

Comment: add in `app-level build.gradle` . The 1st one in your case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you already added the dependency in gradle file.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

defaultConfig {
applicationId "com.example.internet.myapp"
minSdkVersion 15
targetSdkVersion 22
versionCode 1
versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
release {
    minifyEnabled false
    proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),   'proguard-rules.pro'
}
}
}

dependencies {
 compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
 compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'
 compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4+' 
 }
```

[image]

Comment: yes, this is was my first try, but it doesnt work.. which folder should I add in 'libs'?

Comment: @Giuseppe your question is that where you have to add this dependency. but you already added.

Comment: yes, thanks :) but the second question on the bottom of the post is where i have to add the folder that i download from https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils and if i have to add the whole unzipped folder, or some folder inside of it

Comment: no need to add the folder to your project. just add dependency and it will work.

Comment: sorry again, but when I use for example these methods 
KmlLayer layer = new KmlLayer(getMap(), R.raw.kmlFile, getApplicationContext());
                layer.addLayerToMap(); 
and I have to import 
com.google.maps.android.kml.KmlLayer;
I still got errors

Comment: hee there are two ways to add library in android studio
1) Add the dependency in maven repository 
2) Add an external Folder in your Libs folder

you added an maven repository for androidMapUtils so there is no need to add an downloaded folder anywhere .just add and maven repository and  enjoy.....


For Kml layer import  the whole repository don't use sub method import import the whole
 compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
It will work

Comment: Thanks a lot, it made my ideas more clear. But now when i sync and rebuild it says "unable to load maven metadata" :(

Comment: can u upload the screenshot where you added and where error is coming

Comment: I still dont have enough reputation to add images:
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugCompile'
> Could not resolve com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4+.
Required by:
MyApp:app:unspecified
 > Failed to list versions for com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils> Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/maps/android/android-maps-utils/maven-metadata.xml.
> Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/maps/android/android-maps-utils/maven-metadata.xml'
> Connection to https://jcenter.bintray.com refused

Comment: thanks it works properly now. I dont know why but using the user without privileges i have problems with the connection of Android Studio (aslo for downloading SDk libraries)

Comment: That problem apparently is solved, but i dont know if i cannot see the maps anymore on my app because of this: https://developers.google.com/maps/signup
(I havent used/watched them in the last 2 weeks)

Comment: did you used the API key?? which is registered by you?

Comment: i found out.. the problem was that with another user/machine i had to change the key